# Use of unresolved identifier 'WKExtension'

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

i want to make a phone call from Apple Watch too. I imported WatchKit. Then i put this code in my method:

```
if let telURL=NSURL(string:"tel:5553478") {
       let wkExtension=WKExtension.sharedExtension()
       wkExtension.openSystemURL(telURL)
}
```

It shows me an error: Use of unresolved identifier 'WKExtension' in line 2. I don't know what I am doing wrong :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WKExtension` is only available on WatchOS 2.0, as you can see from Apple's prerelease [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKExtension_class/). So I'm guessing you're either not using Xcode 7 or you're working on a v1.0 watch extension.

Create a new target and choose watch OS > Application.

Comment: I am working on Xcode 8.3.2 and targeting deployment target 3.0 for watchOS